# using date_add() to add a date column with another column in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem about using date_add().
I have 1 table that contain 1 date column and 1 integer column.
here is the data example:

```
id        A        B
=====================
1    2014-03-01   30
2    2014-03-05   20
3    2014-03-05   30
4    2014-03-07   100
.         .        .
.         .        .
```

What I want to do is when I input some date (ex: 2014-04-02), I want to select everyone that when the column A added with column B (date_add(A,B)) will result the same as my input. The unit of the column B is day(s). What should I do?
Please help me.

Comment: can you post your query here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DATE_ADD(a, INTERVAL b DAY) = $user_input
```

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/445539/1)

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Thank you Mark!! This is the answer and I have to modify it a little and turn it into this just to make sure:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD(table.a, INTERVAL table.b DAY) = $user_input

Answer (score 0):

The DATE_ADD() function adds a specified time interval to a date.

Syntax:- DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)

Here date is a valid date expression and expr is the number of interval you want to add.

Here is the SQL that you need..

```
$Q = "SELECT * FROM tableName
     WHERE  date_add( A , INTERVAL B DAY) =".$inputDate;
```